# Is there an option to toggle between two units of currency?

Tags: react-intl

With most currencies there two units of currency, for example, pounds/pence, dollars/cents. Is there a way to toggle between these two units when displaying currency data (preferable using `react-intl`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to format numbers as sub-divisions of a currency in the default Intl API (10 cents, 25 paise, etc). Hence, it's also not possible via the react-intl library.